# B2C Built-In Policy, how to handle mandatory parameter differently for different Identity Provider(Local/Azure AD) Sing-in

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity, built-in, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have created Azure B2C Sign-In and Sing-Up policy as Built-In policy. Where i need to collect User First Name, Last Name and Country information.
[image]
Above built-in policy support below two identity provider login.[image].
We need Country attribute information only when local User sign-up very first time. But as we have made Country as mandatory attribute, so it is coming for Azure AD user as well when they login very first time and we don't want to collect any country information for Azure AD users login.
How can we handle this scenario that within Single Built-In policy handle mandatory attribute differently.
Not able to get any thought though whether this will work using custom policy or not. Because User needs to login either sign-in/Up over login page by using above two Identity Providers.

Comment: I'm affraid you can't. Build in policy has a single self asserted page where user needs to enter values you select in "User claims". The only solution is to use custom policies or change your application to have "Login with email" or "Login with AAD" buttons which open different built in policies. The other way might be to have some custom logic in UI template javascript, however, I didn't try it myself and I don't know if that is possible, meaning that you can base the "hiding" logic on any info available to the script. It may also be more difficult if providing values is mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for update wojtkdo, I also had similar thinking but i am also thinking that whether custom policy will help in this case or not because there also we will face similar issue as i need country is mandatory for B2C local user. If you have sample policy file for such scenario. can you please share that.

Comment: You can do it with custom policy, and have different attribute collection pages using a condition on which IdP was used to authenticate via.

Comment: Hi Jas, Can you please provide me any sample policy where i can achieve this. As i am not able to visualize that how this will work with conditional attribute based on IdP selection.